# jquery remove elements which are not in array

Tags: jquery

In the following code how to remove the .e_data which is greater than s_arr.topics.length
For example if s_arr.topics.length = 2 and $(".e_data").length = 5 ..Then in this case want to remove the elements `3rd .e_data,4th .e_data,5 .e_data` how to do this

```
if($(".e_data").length > s_arr.topics.length)
{
$('.e_data').last().remove();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean want to delete a tag which has `length` greater than `s_arr.topics.length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$(".e_data").slice(s_arr_topics.length).remove();
```